# Vuejs loop component and get the emitted data in instant

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I loop a child components that has emitted data and pass to local data in parent but my expectation result is not what i get. It should be in incremental like this. Example

```
Index       Total
0             5
1             7
2             10
3             12
```

here my code:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="data, index in myArr">
      <child-block-1
        :key="index"
        :data="data"
        @emittedData="total += $event"
      />
      <child-block-2 v-if="total > 10" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

The `total` data will add the emitted data, but when i check the total it will always the overall total 12. not the incremental.

**Is there any other solution for this to get what my expected result ?**

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It's unknown what happens in these components

Comment: As @EstusFlask said, It will be difficult to understand what is happening in child component. What is there in the `data` ? Are those incremented integers is in data prop ? You are just emitting those from child or is there any other logic ?